# Dependend dropdowns not refreshing properly in Yii2

Tags: yii2, kartik-v

I have a problem that's driving me mad. I have two Select2-Dropdowns showing employees, one for dayshift, the other for nightshift. The employee selected for dayshift should be removed from the nightshift dropdown and vice versa. I managed to refresh the nightshift dropdown when an employee is selected in the dayshift dropdown, but when I select an employee in the nightshift dropdown he isn't removed from the dayshift dropdown...

here's the snippet from the _form.php:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'customer_id')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
                'options'=>['id'=>'customer-id','class'=>'customer-id shift-name'],
                'disabled' => !$create_jn,
                    'data' => ArrayHelper::map(customer::find()->where(['active_yn' => 1])->orderBy(['name'=>SORT_ASC])->all(),'customer_id','name')
                    ]); ?>
            
            <?=
              $form->field($model, 'site_id')->widget(DepDrop::classname(), [
                    'options'=>['id'=>'site-id','class'=>'site-id shift-name'],
                    'disabled' => $disable_yn,
                    'type' => DepDrop::TYPE_SELECT2,
                    'pluginOptions'=>[                        
                        'depends'=>['cutomer-id'],  
                        'placeholder'=>'Please choose',
                        'url'=>Url::to(['/site/customer-site']),
                        // 'initialize'=>true,
                    ]]); 
            ?>
            
             <?= $form->field($model, 'site_employee_id')->widget(DepDrop::classname(), [
                    'options'=>['id'=>'site-employee-id'],
                    'disabled' => $disable_yn,
                    'type' => DepDrop::TYPE_SELECT2,
                    'pluginOptions'=>[
                        'depends'=>['customer-id'],
                        'placeholder'=>'Please choose',
                        'url'=>Url::to(['/site/customer']),
                        'params' => ['site-employee-night-id'],
                        // 'initialize'=>true,
                    ]
                ]); ?>
        
             <?= $form->field($model, 'bst_leiter_nacht_id')->widget(DepDrop::classname(), [
                    'options'=>['id'=>'site-employee-night-id'],
                    'disabled' => $disable_yn,
                    'type' => DepDrop::TYPE_SELECT2,
                    'pluginOptions'=>[                        
                        'depends'=>['customer-id','site-employee-id'],
                        'placeholder'=>'Please choose',
                        'url'=>Url::to(['/site/customer-night']),                        
                        'params' => ['site-employee-id'],
                        'initialize'=>true,
                    ]
                ]); ?>
```

and here's the controller:

```
public function actionCustomer() {
        Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
        $out=array();
        if (isset($_POST['depdrop_parents'])) {
            $parents = $_POST['depdrop_parents'];
            
            if (isset($_POST['depdrop_params'])) {
                $params = $_POST['depdrop_params'];

                if ($parents != null) {
                    $customer_id = $parents[0];

                    if($params != null) {
                        $site_employee_night_id = $params[0];

                        $out= \frontend\models\Employee::find()
                            ->where(['customer_id'=>$customer_id])
                            ->andWhere(['<>','employee_id', $site_employee_night_id])
                            ->select(['employee_id as id','CONCAT(firstname," ",lastname) as name'])
                            ->orderBy('lastname')->asArray()->all();

                        return ['output'=>$out, 'selected'=>''];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return ['output'=>'', 'selected'=>''];
    }

 public function actionCustomerNight() {
        Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
        $out=array();
        if (isset($_POST['depdrop_parents'])) {
            $parents = $_POST['depdrop_parents'];
            
            if (isset($_POST['depdrop_params'])) {
                $params = $_POST['depdrop_params'];

                if ($parents != null) {
                    $customer_id = $parents[0];

                    if($params != null) {
                        $site_employee_id = $params[0];

                        $out= \frontend\models\Employee::find()
                            ->where(['customer_id'=>$customer_id])
                            ->andWhere(['<>','employee_id', $site_employee_id])
                            ->select(['employee_id as id','CONCAT(firstname," ",lastname) as name'])
                            ->orderBy('lastname')->asArray()->all();

                        return ['output'=>$out, 'selected'=>''];
                    }
                }
            }
        }        
        return ['output'=>'', 'selected'=>''];
    }
```

Any help, tips, hints would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that night shift dropdown depends on dayshift dropdown and gets refreshed when dayshift one is changed. Since dayshift dropdown depends only on customer-id it won't be refreshed (function in controller wont refresh data) when you change night shift dropdown.

On nightshift add onchange event and trigger refresh manually

Comment: Hi Filip, thanks a lot. I will try as you suggested and tell you if I succeeded.